# Como faço para o sublime text marcar a uma palavra como keyword?

Tags: php, sublime-text-2

Eu gosto de usar o sublime text para desenvolver algumas coisas em php.
Mas tem uma coisa que ainda não foi implementado.

Quando crio um `trait`, o `sublime text` não "colore" a palavra-chave `trait` como esperado.

Como posso fazer para o sublime text marcar as palavras abaixo como palavras-chaves?

`insteadof`, `trait`, `callable`

Existe algum pacote do PHP 5.4+ para instalar no sublime?

[image: problema com a marcação da palavra trait]

Comment: Acho que ainda não tem solução para isso. Veja: http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/100149-php-54-short-array-syntax-highlight-in-functions/ Mas posso estar enganado, vamos ver se alguém não aparece com uma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É algo relativamente simples. Você pode editar o pacote sintático atual do PHP e incluir as palavras reservadas. Os arquivos de definição sintática possuem, por padrão, a extensão `.tmLanguage`. Você precisa localizá-los e alterá-los.

## Sublime Text 3

Localize o diretório de instalação dos pacotes nativos. Por padrão, você pode encontrá-lo, no Linux, em `/opt/sublime-text/Packages`. Localize o pacote referente ao PHP, provavelmente `PHP.sublime-package`. Talvez você precise dar permissão para poder modificar os arquivos. Arquivos `.sublime-package` são apenas arquivos zipados com uma extensão diferente. Você deve poder descompactá-los normalmente. Abra o arquivo `PHP.tmLanguage` e insira ao conjunto de expressões regulares das palavras-chave as novas *keywords*. Salve-o e recompacte-o, restaure sua extensão e reinicie o editor.